# Development proxy not working in react vite

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, vercel, netlify

I was trying to deploy my vite react application in vercel or netlify. I hosted it's backend part in render, Now backend is working, but when i hosted in frontend, the request URL change to hosted URL because I used vite proxy to use shortcut URL but it's not working in devlopment,

Example of my vite config

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VitePWA(manifestForPlugin),
    react(),
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://sample__.onrender.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace("/api", ""),
      },
    },
  },
  build: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://sample__.onrender.com/", 
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace("/api", ""),
      }
    }
  }
});
```

so when i call api my url is like:
`api/auth/login/`

so in localhost, it will became, `localhost:8000/auth/login/`

but when i did it from dev server of netlify or vercel it become like `vercel/netlify url/api/auth/login/`

In localhost my backend is runnning in 8000 and frontend is runningin 5173

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue arises from the way you've set up the proxy in your Vite configuration, and how the frontend application is handling these proxied API requests in different environments.

Here's how you can modify your Vite configuration to handle API proxying more consistently:

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VitePWA(manifestForPlugin),
    react(),
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://sample__.onrender.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Ensure that your API calls in the frontend code are relative to the /api path:

```
// Example of an API call in your frontend code
fetch('/api/auth/login', {
  // other fetch options
})
  .then((response) => {
    // handle response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle error
  });
```

This setup should work consistently across different environments. However, keep in mind that when you deploy to platforms like Vercel or Netlify, the environment variables or settings for your backend URL might need adjustment to ensure proper communication between frontend and backend.

When deploying to different environments, you might need to dynamically set the backend URL based on the current environment. This could involve using environment variables or configuring the backend URL during the build process for each environment.